# UITableViewCell Image not resizing after rotation

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am having trouble resizing images in my UITableViewCell after the screen rotates. In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I detect the width of the device, and if the width is less than 480 I set the image to the screens width, and then set the height to the (images height / images width * screen width) to keep the image scaled. If the width of the device is greater than 480 I do the same thing, except I set the width equal to half of the screen, making the scaled image a little bit smaller.

Below is an image I drew of how the page looks with both portrait and landscape layout. When I rotate from landscape to portrait the visible images still remain on the screen and do not re-size unless I scroll to the point where they leave the screen.

[image]

The same thing works when I go from portrait to landscape, it leaves a big open space on the right side until I scroll down, then it loads just fine. I have a feeling this is something simple such as adding an autoresizingmask, but I cannot figure out where to put it and how to address it:

```
[self.myTableView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
[self.myTableView setAutoresizingMask:
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |
    UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Below is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIndentifier = @"BasicCell";
    UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIndentifier];
    myCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIndentifier];

    CGRect result = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds;
    CGFloat width = CGRectGetWidth(result);
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetHeight(result);

    UIInterfaceOrientation interfaceOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)){
        result.size = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    } else if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {
        result.size = CGSizeMake(height, width);
    }

    if(result.size.width <= 480) {
        Companies *item = _feedItems[indexPath.row];
        myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,CGRectGetWidth(self.listTableView.bounds), (item.imageName.size.height / item.imageName.size.width) * CGRectGetWidth(self.listTableView.bounds))];
        myImageView.tag = indexPath.row;
        myImageView.image = item.imageName;

        [myCell addSubview:myImageView];
    }

    if(result.size.width > 480) {
        NSLog(@"IndexPath.row: %d, feedItems: %d",indexPath.row, _feedItems.count);
        if((indexPath.row*2+1) <= _feedItems.count) {
            Companies *item = _feedItems[indexPath.row * 2];
            myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,CGRectGetWidth(self.listTableView.bounds) / 2, (item.imageName.size.height / item.imageName.size.width) / 2 * CGRectGetWidth(self.listTableView.bounds))];
            myImageView.tag = indexPath.row*2;
            myImageView.image = item.imageName;

            [myCell addSubview:myImageView];

            if ((indexPath.row*2+1) < _feedItems.count) {
                Companies *item2 = _feedItems[(indexPath.row * 2) + 1];
                myImageView2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.listTableView.bounds) / 2,0,CGRectGetWidth(self.listTableView.bounds) / 2, (item.imageName.size.height / item.imageName.size.width) / 2 * CGRectGetWidth(self.listTableView.bounds))];
                myImageView2.tag = indexPath.row*2+1;
                myImageView2.image = item2.imageName;

                [myCell addSubview:myImageView2];
            }
        } 
    }
    return myCell;
}
```

I am certain I had the right idea at some point, but everything I have tried has not made a difference. My gut feeling tells me I need to add the autoresizingmask to the myImageView, however that is drawn in the cellForRowAtIndexPath. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If its a problem that is resolved when the cells are reloaded a simple call to `[self.myTableView reloadData]` should do the trick.

Comment: Ahhh, so like `- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [self.listTableView reloadData];
}` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A call to `[self.myTableView reloadData]` should fix it if the cells only need to be reloaded (seems to be the problem as when you scroll the issue is fixed).

You can add something which looks like this:

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation {
    [self.myTableView reloadData]
}
```

Comment: You have fromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) repeated twice xD

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 8, you'll want to do this in the view controller:

```
-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator
{
    [super viewWillTransitionToSize:size withTransitionCoordinator:coordinator];

    // Resizes the table cell rows to match the new size.
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> context) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } completion:nil];
}
```